# backup each tables of all databases and save it to local directory?

Tags: mysql, backup

I have looked everywhere.. but not able to find any perfect solution (free) where I can download backup of all databases->tables individually so I can restore any table anytime I want and I do not have to restore whole database..

I am using mysql database, I have like 10-15 databases and 100+ tables in each.

I can see "Auto backup for mysql" does that. but its almost 100 bucks.. I want to know if I can do with terminal or any other tool.. I want to do backup everyday.. and want to have each table.sql file with the date and time..

Is it possible??

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. I've edited your question to remove the greetings. Please remember than in SO you will say "thank you" by voting/accepting answers. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for the details.

Answer (score 1):

use `mysqldump`

an example of what you want

```
mysqldump --user=dbuser --password --tab=~/output/dir --all-databases
```

that will put a seperate sql file in ~/output/dir for all databases which user has read and lock access to

a full list of commands found here

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: Thanks for your help.. I am getting this error.. --databases or --all-databases can't be used with --tab .. and Can I save it directly on my windows PC rather then storing it to server and then download?

Answer (score 0):

Start by creating a list of tables

If you are doing all databases, do this:

```
SQLSTMT="SELECT CONCAT(table_schema,'.',table_name)"
SQLSTMT="${SQLSTMT} FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema NOT IN"
SQLSTMT="#{SQLSTMT} ('information_schema','mysql','performance_schema')"
mysql -h... -u... -p... -ANe"${SQLSTMT}" > /tmp/ListOfTables.txt
```

If you are doing only a specific database (like `mydb`), then do this:

```
SQLSTMT="SELECT CONCAT(table_schema,'.',table_name)"
SQLSTMT="${SQLSTMT} FROM information_schema.tables "
SQLSTMT="${SQLSTMT} WHERE table_schema='mydb'"
mysql -h... -u... -p... -ANe"${SQLSTMT}" > /tmp/ListOfTables.txt
```

Then dump all tables in groups of 10

```
TARGET_FOLDER=/backups/mysql
COMMIT_COUNT=0
COMMIT_LIMIT=10
for DBTB in `cat /tmp/ListOfTables.txt`
do
    DB=`echo ${DBTB} | sed 's/\./ /g' | awk '{print $1}'`
    TB=`echo ${DBTB} | sed 's/\./ /g' | awk '{print $2}'`
    BACKUP_FILE=${TARGET_FOLDER}/${DB}_${TB}.sql.gz
    MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS="-h... -u... -p... --hex-blob --triggers"
    mysqldump ${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} ${DB} ${TB} | gzip > ${BACKUP_FILE} &
    (( COMMIT_COUNT++ ))
    if [ ${COMMIT_COUNT} -eq ${COMMIT_LIMIT} ]
    then
        COMMIT_COUNT=0
        wait
    fi
done
if [ ${COMMIT_COUNT} -gt 0 ]
then
    wait
fi
```

Give it a Try !!!